# tooltip anywhere in the screen-- vc++ express edition

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, tooltip

I tried looking for sample code for displaying a tooltip anywhere in the screen, but mostly are using/including MFC headers

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/tooltipzen.aspx?fid=4069&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=1#xx0xx) and its way of displaying the tooltip is what i need, but i cant rebuild/study the source when i try to use it in VC++ express

Q: is there a way to simply code it using VC++ Express Edition? Anyone can post a working sample

note: I specifically need this in C++, though my tool is limited in VC++ express

thank you

Comment: You might want to have to qt and [QToolTip][1] : it's 100% C++ and compilable with VC++ express edition, thus it should fit with your requirements. 


  [1]: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtooltip.html

Comment: thanks Bruce, will check on it

Comment: That code is just using plain old Win32 APIs; it should work fine with VC++ Express, though I think you will have to download the Platform SDK separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/). This is a lightweight wrapper around WINAPI. There you can find CToolTipCtrl class and some samples. I guess it should be compatible with VC++ express.